# How to get multiple file upload with different name

Tags: php, html, forms, file, file-upload

I want to upload multiple files and get the name of file to be upload:

I have for a type_demand some type_file to be uploaded

E.g : for type_demand A i can upload type_file X, Y, Z

In my php i want to get the 3 files and know what is the X, the Y and the Z.

here an example of my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" 

enctype="multipart/form-data">
  

  <label for="type">Files to upload:</label>


  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="FormControlFile1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">X</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file col-sm-10" id="FormControlFile1" name="myfile[]">
  </div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="FormControlFile2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Y</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file col-sm-10" id="FormControlFile2" name="myfile[]">
  </div>
 
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="FormControlFile3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Z</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file col-sm-10" id="FormControlFile3" name="myfile[]">
  </div>
  

</div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="upload">Upload</button>
   
</form>
```

and this is my php code:

```
<?php  
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 
 if(isset($_FILES['myfile'])){
     $tmp_arr= $_FILES['myfile'];
 }
 // Create an array with desired structure.
 for($i=0; $i<count($tmp_arr['name']); $i++){
     $files[] = array(
         'name'     =>  $tmp_arr['name'][$i],
         'type'     =>  $tmp_arr['type'][$i],
         'tmpName'  =>  $tmp_arr['tmp_name'][$i],
         'error'    =>  $tmp_arr['error'][$i],
         'size'     =>  $tmp_arr['size'][$i],
    //i want to have another information here to know if it's X, Y or Z file 
     );
 }

 
foreach($files as $file){
         echo '<br/>'.$file['name'] .' is for :' ;
}
```

as result i want to have for example:

NameOfFile1 is for: X

NameOfFile2 is for: Y

NameOfFile3 is for: Z

Thank you

Comment: well occ 0 will be the first and occ 1 will be the second etc etc

Comment: I would be tempted to call them `name="myfile1"` and `name="myfile2"` etc and then you know which is whicch

Comment: Use an array syntax - ie: `myfile["NameOfFile1"]`, `myfile["NameOfFile2"]` etc - it is easy then in PHP to identify which is which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to be able to assign the name ( whatever you want within reason ) to the field in the HTML as you are already using an `array style` syntax. For example:

```
<?php
    $field='myfile';
    $errors=array();

    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_FILES[ $field ] ) ){
        $obj=$_FILES[ $field ];
        
        foreach( $obj['name'] as $index => $void ){
            /*
                $index refers to the name assign in `myfile['fieldname']`
            */
            $name=$obj['name'][ $index ];
            $tmp=$obj['tmp_name'][ $index ];
            $error=$obj['error'][ $index ];
            $type=$obj['type'][ $index ];
            $size=$obj['size'][ $index ];
            $ext=strtolower(pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            
            // do stuff...
            printf(
                '
                <h1>%s</h1>
                <pre>%s</pre>
                ',
                $index,
                print_r($obj,true)
            );
            
            //next
        }
    }
?>
```

And the modified HTML to include `X,Y & Z` as names. IDs removed and elements located within the label themselves as it means less HTML code.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Files to upload:</legend>
        
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                X : <input type="file" class="form-control-file col-sm-10" name="myfile[X]">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                Y: <input type="file" class="form-control-file col-sm-10" name="myfile[Y]">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                Z: <input type="file" class="form-control-file col-sm-10" name="myfile[Z]">
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to re-invent the wheel.

The [jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) (by heyageek) does all that you want and is minimal and time-tested. *(I've been using it successfully for years)*

Note that he has sample code for the [client side](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) (jQuery) and for the [server](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) (PHP).

You will want to look at the `formData` and/or `dynamicFormData` features, which allow you to collect other data before submit and send them (along with the uploaded file) to your back-end processing file.

```
dynamicFormData: function()
{
    //var data ="XYZ=1&ABCD=2";
    var data ={"XYZ":1,"ABCD":2};
    return data;        
}
```

Here is a [sample upload script](https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/blob/master/php/upload.php) that will show you how to get the names of the files that were uploaded (see line 18):

```
$fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
```

Note that the `myfile` matches up with the filename in the javascript ajax block:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url:"YOUR_FILE_UPLOAD_URL",
    fileName:"myfile"
    });
});
</script>
```

Study the examples on the "Getting Started" tab, and on the "Server Side" (PHP Files, up top) and you'll have all your problems resolved in minutes.

#### Reference

Here's another example that uses the plugin: [PHP file upload inside modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005844/php-file-upload-inside-modal-window/24006553#24006553)